# Twilio sending error The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts//Messages.json was not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

going through this course to build ROR app and sending a twilio message to verify persons mobile number. I get the error" The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts//Messages.json was not found" found a previous question request however they did not have much code to review and he mentioned that he finally has it working mentioned he had a null variable of $sid and token; not sure what to verify. I tried both test and production sid and token #s from my acct. Thanks so much for your attention.

initailizer/twilio.rb

```
    Twilio.configure do |config|
      config.account_sid = ENV['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
      config.auth_token = ENV['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
    end
```

models/user.rb

```
def generate_pin
    self.pin = SecureRandom.hex(2)
    self.phone_verified = false
    save
end

def send_pin
@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new
@client.messages.create(
  from: '+15812345678',
  to: self.phone_number,
  body: "Your pin is #{self.pin}"
)
end

def verify_pin(entered_pin)
update(phone_verified: true) if self.pin == entered_pin
end
```

Application.yml

```
 TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID: '12345678901234567'

 TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN: '123434567890123456'

 TWILIO_NUMBER: '+15878551234'
```

users controller

```
def update_phone_number
     current_user.update_attributes(user_params)
     current_user.generate_pin
     current_user.send_pin

     redirect_to edit_user_registration_path, notice: "Saved!"

   rescue Exception => e
     redirect_to edit_user_registration_path, alert: "#{e.message}"
   end

   def verify_phone_number
     current_user.verify_pin(params[:user][:pin])

     if current_user.phone_verified
       flash[:notice] = "FYi Your phone number is verified"
     else
       flash[:alert] = "Cannot verify your phone number"
     end

     redirect_to edit_user_registration_path

   rescue Exception => e
     redirect_to edit_user_registration_path, alert: "#{e.message}"
   end

   private

     def user_params
       params.require(:user).permit(:phone_number, :pin)
     end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but could you try this

```
def send_pin
  account_sid = 'your-account-sid'
  auth_token = 'your-auth-token'
  @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token

  @client.messages.create({
    from: '+15812345678',
    to: self.phone_number,
    body: "Your pin is #{self.pin}"
  })
end
```

Comment: wonderful thank you it worked I had the sid and token keys as you outlined now I'm going to try with the figaro gem hidden keys i.e ENV['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']